# React get if element scrolled to the right

Tags: reactjs, scroll, event-listener

I have an `overflow: scroll` div, and I'd like to check if it is scrolled to the right. How can I get an event listener for scroll in React and how can I calculate if it's scrolled to the right horisontally?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elem = () => {
    const [isScrolledRight, setIsScrolledRight] = useState(false)
    const handleScroll = (elem: any) => {
      const scrollLeft = elem.target.scrollLeft
      const scrollWidth = elem.target.scrollWidth
      const clientWidth = elem.target.clientWidth
      setIsScrolledRight(scrollLeft + clientWidth == scrollWidth)
    }

    // use isScrolledRight anywhere you need

    return (
      <div onScroll={handleScroll.bind(this)} /> // this should be horisontally scrollable
    )
  }
```